# Is onBufferAvailable called on a new thread?

Tags: android

I checked and the code inside the callback `onBufferAvailable` of `Allocation.OnBufferAvailableListener` is called in a different thread than the UI thread. Is it true? And if so why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: `I checked` if you did, then `Is it true` - yes. Show how you checked, and then we can say if you checked correctly.

Comment: I used `Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()` to check. So why the callback is called in a separate thread? Thanks.

Comment: That's how it is designed. You should ask this question to Google. Anyway, you can easily run anything on the UI thread .

Comment: No, that's fine. Indeed, I want to run it on a separate thread( using renderscript to convert yuv to rgb ). Initially, I created a background thread to run the renderscript, but I guess it's redundant as the callback is already happening in a separate thread? 
ps: this example runs the renderscript in a separate thread: [https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/hdrviewfinder/ViewfinderProcessor.java], isn't it redundant?
Thanks.

Comment: I think that it happens in separate thread because it's caller operates in separate thread. So it is actually buffering on the separate thread (IO operation?). But if your listener contains heavy load code, it might be sense to use one more thread to perform it because it might slow down that buffering.